# How to thread a function in python that has two returned values

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have a python function that requires the user enter an array of data; at which point the function works on the data and produces two arrays which are returned to the main program.  In this question I am including a greatly simplified example from which I hope I can solicit some advice or help.  I have created a function titled "Test_Function" that requires the programmer supply an array of data titled "Array", which in this case has a length of 5000.  The function works on the data and produces two sets of arrays titled "Result1" and "Result2" which are returned to the user in the main program as the variables "Res1" and "Res2".  I would like to thread the function so that the function "Test_Function" so that one thread will work on half of the input array and the other thread will work on the other half and then combine them back together in the main program for both output arrays "Result1" and "Result2"/"Res1" and "Res2".  I described a scenario where I would produce two threads, but I would like to make it generic enough so that it could run a user defined number of threads. How do I do this with the thread functionality?

```
import numpy as np     
def Test_Function(Array):
    Result1 = Array*np.pi*(1-Array)
    Result2 = Array+478.5 + (1/Array)
    return(np.array(Result1,dtype=float), np.array(Result2,dtype=float))
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Dependent_Array = np.linspace(1.0,5000.0,num=5000)
    Res1, Res2 = Test_Function(Dependent_Array)
# eof
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a ThreadPool to which assign async tasks:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def sub1(Array):
    return Array * np.pi * (1-Array)

def sub2(Array):
    return Array + 478.5 + (1/Array)

def Test_Function(Array):
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=2)
    res1 = pool.apply_async(sub1, (Array,))
    res2 = pool.apply_async(sub2, (Array,))
    return (np.array(res1.get(),dtype=float), np.array(res2.get(),dtype=float))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Dependent_Array = np.linspace(1.0,5000.0,num=5000)
    Res1, Res2 = Test_Function(Dependent_Array)
```

This module is not very well documented, but, basically, it creates a pool of workers to which you can assign subroutines to execute. The method `get()` of the result object created by `apply_async` will return the result only when the corresponding thread has finished its operations.